# IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek Wavefile

Tags: sound, python, io

Im trying to use wavebender library to create music and get data out of music. I get this error don't know how to solve this.

```
from wavebender import *
from itertools import *
import sys

def ncycles(iterable, n):
    "Returns the sequence elements n times"
    return chain.from_iterable(repeat(tuple(iterable), n))

def waves():
    l = int(44100*0.4) # each note lasts 0.4 seconds

    return cycle(chain(ncycles(chain(islice(damped_wave(frequency=440.0, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l),
                                     islice(damped_wave(frequency=261.63, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l),
                                     islice(damped_wave(frequency=329.63, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l)), 3),
                       islice(damped_wave(frequency=440.0, amplitude=0.1, length=3*l), 3*l),

                       ncycles(chain(islice(damped_wave(frequency=293.66, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l),
                                     islice(damped_wave(frequency=261.63, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l),
                                     islice(damped_wave(frequency=293.66, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l)), 2),
                       chain(islice(damped_wave(frequency=293.66, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l),
                             islice(damped_wave(frequency=329.63, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l),
                             islice(damped_wave(frequency=293.66, amplitude=0.1, length=int(l/4)), l)),
                       islice(damped_wave(frequency=261.63, amplitude=0.1, length=3*l), 3*l)))

channels = ((waves(),), (waves(), white_noise(amplitude=0.001),))

samples = compute_samples(channels, None)
write_wavefile(sys.stdout, samples, None)
```

Generates this error;

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/nerzid/PycharmProjects/Deneme/assets/beep.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nerzid/PycharmProjects/Deneme/assets/beep.py", line 28, in <module>
RIFFRIFF    write_wavefile(sys.stdout, samples, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wavebender/__init__.py", line 98, in write_wavefile
    w.writeframesraw(frames)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line 422, in writeframesraw
    self._ensure_header_written(len(data))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line 473, in _ensure_header_written
    self._write_header(datasize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line 481, in _write_header
    self._form_length_pos = self._file.tell()
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek
Exception IOError: (29, 'Illegal seek') in <bound method Wave_write.__del__ of <wave.Wave_write instance at 0x7fbe63ecad88>> ignored
```

Any advice would be appreciated.